ADE configurations of curves on toric variety.
I was told in a lecture the fact that toric surfaces admit no ADE configurations of curves. In particular, one would have that the canonical model of a toric variety of dimension 2 has no ADE singularities so it's smooth.
Does anyone have a reference for this fact? I have not been able to find any myself.

Whatever an ADE configuration of curves is, I imagine that a chain of $(-2)$-curves should count as one. For sure one can find toric surfaces containing such chains.

Hey, you are right. I found a reference now, $A_n$ singularities do exist for toric surfaces. But $D_n$, $E_6$, $E_7$ and $E_8$ do not. See 10.1 in the book Toric Varieties by Cox, Little and Schenck.
